# Project Server 2013 (SharePoint Based) send email when the task are sent to approval

Tags: workflow, email, project-server

I install the Project Server Web App in my SharePoint 2013 farm.
I need create a workflow to send email when the task are sent to approval, but the list "Approvals" is not showed in "Site Content".

Does anyone know where this list is stored?

Comment: check this one http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn458867(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: This article is to create a workflow to approve, but in PWA already exist this functionality. I need send email when a new approval is requested.